# Can I install Node.js on Endless OS efficiently?

Tags: linux, debian, node.js

Endless OS is a **linux-debian** distribution that runs on the Endless Mini computer.

I found out about Endless form this [itsfoss](https://itsfoss.com/4-linux-based-mini-pc-buy-2015/)

See this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endless_Computers).

I'm trying to find a small PC that runs a **nix OS** and Node.

I'm not sure what is required of Node to run how to verify that their Endless Mini / Endless OS can run it.

I did try to contact Endless with no response.

I did find this wikipedia line a bit hmmm ...

> Unlike most Linux distributions, it uses a read-only root filesystem
>   managed by OSTree and Flatpak for application delivery and update.

Can someone make an EndlessOS tag, I don't have the rep yet?

**Update:**

I got a response from their customer support and they are telling me that they can run Node but it has to use something called Podman.

I'm not sure if this is a good idea and that I will get the full power of Node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can run **Node.js** on **EndlessOS** easily.

[**Flathub**](https://flathub.org/home) is a repository using [**Flatpak**](https://flatpak.org/).

From this repository you can install **Podman** and using Podman you can install Node.js

As a bonus because you are using a container.  It will be easy to deploy to multiple platforms.

**Links**

https://podman.io